# Is temperature the speed of electrons?

Tags: thermodynamics, electrons, temperature, speed

Back in the middle school (which I guess was about 10 years ago) I remember being taught that the [temperature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperature) of an atom is basically the speed of electrons circling the nucleus which kinda made sense - lower temperature, lower speed so the matter is better at holding together (being solid).

I don't really know if this was outdated knowledge or simplification (or I remember incorrectly) but my question is:

**How true is it that temperature is defined by the speed of the electrons and, thus, the lower the temperature the slower the electrons go around the nucleus?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a given orbital, electron motion has nothing to do with temperature.

Atoms do have a variety of electronic states and, at higher temperatures, the higher energy states are more likely to be populated.

Temperature, however, is most commonly determined by the translational motion of the nucleus of the atoms.  Let $v$ be the speed of a nucleus of an atom in a gas.  Let $\langle v^2 \rangle$ be the average square speed of those nuclei.  Temperature and mean energy of translational motion in a gas are related as follows: $$\frac{3}{2} kT = \frac{1}{2} m \langle v^2\rangle$$ where $k$ is Boltzmann's constant, $T$ is temperature, and $m$ is the atom's mass.

Comment: Electrons in orbitals do not have a velocity distribution. That is dangerous semi-classical nonsense that one should never propagate. Your formula for the average kinetic energy of ideal gas molecules is wrong.

Comment: Just to see if we are on the same page, would allow that the orbital wavefunction defines a position distribution?

Comment: No, but this is not the place for me to give you a lesson in quantum mechanics.

Comment: Wavefunctions do define probability distributions for position. In quantum mechanics, this is called [the Born Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rule).  You can also read about it [here](http://webpages.ursinus.edu/lriley/courses/p212/lectures/node34.html).  Images of, for example, spatial probability distributions for the hydrogen atom are shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mechanics).

Comment: The Born rule gives you a distribution for a measurement, it doesn't give you a distribution for the position of an electron (or any other particle). That is a fine but very important difference between classical physics and quantum mechanics. In order to measure a position, you have to exchange real quanta with the atom, while there is no such exchange for the unmeasured atom. I know, we don't teach this stuff right in beginners classes and layman literature... but we should. Remove your first sentence and correct your formula and I will retract the down vote. Fair?

Comment: I apologize for speaking in shorthand: you are right that it is a distribution for a measured value.  Answer updated.

Comment: To be honest I don't fully understand this answer but I am guessing it's correct.

Comment: @MaurycyZarzycki This question is complex: it touches on quantum mechanics and statistical mechanics.  If there is some point, though, that you want me to attempt to clarify, just ask.

Comment: I guess the most basic and correct answer to my question as stated is "No, that's not true". I am curious now, though - what's the difference between an atom of hydrogen of the temperature 10K and 100K? How is the energy from the higher temperature "stored"?

Comment: At 10K and normal pressure, hydrogen is a liquid.  When you heat it to 100K, energy goes primarily to three places.  The first is the heat of evaporation (the energy needed to separate the molecules) so it can become a gas. The second is the random translational motion of the molecules.  The third is random rotation of the molecules.

Comment: -1 For the wrong answer and the weird focus on gas while the question did not mention it.

Answer (score -4):

it seams to me that a low temperature would cause energy to dissipate from the  electron orbit. This would more importantly cause the orbit of the electron decrease its distance from the proton/Nucleus core. causing the electron to actually move more quickly around the core. this is the real reason for Thermal Expansion. I find it highly improbable that there is ever a distance between electrons as stated in so many. I understand the scientific communities desire to be correct. but, everything that i read about the atom, makes me think that nobody has really got a grasp of real physics. One last thing. electrostatic shock has been blamed on lack of humidity for too long. If the electrons are moving faster in colder temperature, then it seams to me that this is the reason for ESD in colder environments

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Please notice [we deal with mainstream Physics here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4539/168783), meaning we are searching for answers which are widely accepted by the scientific community.

Comment: see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/temper.html  ,